# HTML: How can I insert links into ordered and unordered lists?

Tags: html, css, list, hyperlink

I'm creating a website for fun. How can you insert a link inside an order/unordered list?

Also, what is the `<li></li>` tag?

Comment: [Did you do any research before posting here?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element#List_of_all_HTML_elements)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth My first time posting here (Even though in this account there is like 5 posts already). I didn't know I had to do prior research before this.

Comment: I suggest reading the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/about)...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

`li` stands for "list item". This is the only tag you can have as a direct child of `<ul>...</ul>`, so you have to put your links inside the `<li>`.

Answer (score 6):

I created an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/yVdvx/7/) for you.

Here is the code of my jsfiddle:

```
<p id="top">This is the top of the file</p>

<ul> Favourite sports
<li><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Football">Football</a></li>
<li><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tennis">Tennis</a></li>
<li><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rugby_football">Rugby</a></li>
</ul>



<p><a href="#top">This link goes to the top</a></p>
```

The tag li refers to list item.
Links are written the same way in ordered and unordered lists.